# How to compute $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to do this following problem

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$

It seems the answer is $9$ but I don't know how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: For limits:  $\lim_{x \to \infty}$.  As for the problem -- do you know (or are you allowed to use) L'hopital's rule?

Comment: HINT: $9x=\sqrt{81x^2}$

Answer (score 7):

**Key idea:** For $x \geq 0$, we have $\sqrt{x^2} = x$. Factor $x^2$ from inside the radical:

$$
\frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
=\frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right)}}
=\frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}
=\frac{9x}{x\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}
=\frac{9}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}
$$
for $x> 0$. Now, when $x\to \infty$, what is the limit of ${\frac{1}{x^2}+1}$? Therefore, what is the limit of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}$? And finally, what is the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}}$?

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{9x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=$

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{81x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=$

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{81x^2}{x^2+1}}=$

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{81}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=$

$\sqrt{\frac{81}{1+0}}=$

$9$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to Clement C.'s one:

$1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} \ge \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \ge \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2} +\sqrt{1}} =\frac{x}{x +1} = \frac{x+1-1}{x +1} = 1 - \frac{1}{x+1} \xrightarrow{x \to \infty} 1  $

$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} 9* \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = 9$